# Labels not showing output for random simulation

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, label

I have a class project to create a tic tac toe simulations (game is not played by people) where O's and X's automatically generate when the New Game button is clicked. I am having trouble with the code to get the labels to show the output.

Using a 2D array type INT to simulate the game board, it should store a 0 or 1 in each of the 9 elements and produce a O or X. There also needs to be a label to display if X or O wins.

Here is my code so far ( I know there isn't much, I'm completely lost):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        const int ROWS = 3;
        const int COLS = 3;

        int[,] gameBoard = new int[ROWS, COLS];

        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            { gameBoard[row, col]= rand.Next(2); }
        }


    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: We don't see a reference to any labels in your code.

Comment: I know, this is the problem I am trying to solve. labels1-9 are the names, I'm not understanding how to take the randomly generated results and have the labels show an X or O based on what is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Win Forms labels get populated unless the current event process finishes completely. If you want to update the labels with X and O while you may use the control property InvokeRequired (boolean) and after assigning the value to label call label.Refresh() function. I will suggest fork a thread on hitting start button and do the for loop -> random.next() inside the thread. Try with these changes. All the Best!!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to programming, could you provide an example of your explanation? We have not covered what you are referring to in class yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int ROWS = 3;
        const int COLS = 3;

        const int WIDTH = 100;
        const int HEIGHT = 100;
        const int SPACE = 20;
        static TextBox[,] gameBoard;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gameBoard = new TextBox[ROWS, COLS];

            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                {
                    TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();
                    newTextBox.Multiline = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(newTextBox);
                    newTextBox.Height = HEIGHT;
                    newTextBox.Width = WIDTH;
                    newTextBox.Top = SPACE + (row * (HEIGHT + SPACE));
                    newTextBox.Left = SPACE + (col * (WIDTH + SPACE));
                    gameBoard[row, col] = newTextBox;
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This does not fit the project criteria, we are required to use label controls in a windows form.

Comment: Then simply change the control type from a text box to a label.  Everything will be the same except a label doesn't have a Multiline (so delete this line).

Comment: I have already created the form, I am needing it to randomly generate a 0 or 1 and assign a O or X to each label.

Comment: You would then have to index each label by row and column.  I added the 9 Labels into the gameBoard array.  So you would need to do the same.  Creating the labels dynamically makes changes a lot easier.